# Replicate mnesia database to Mysql

Tags: mysql, ejabberd, mnesia

I have installed ejabberd on an AWS EC2 instance and am using the smack library to connect to it with my android app. At the moment the ejabberd server is using mnesia as the database, however I want to perform some complex queries on some of the data (mainly the MUC room names), as SQL will predominantly the best solution for this, I was wondering if it was possible to replicate the required data to an external MySQL database that I could then query.

Is this possible or am i better looking at a different approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no module built into ejabberd to replicate data in Mnesia to MySQL. However, the usual approach is to use the backend you need for each feature. If you want `mod_muc` to store data into MySQL instead of Mnesia, you can just change the backend to odbc (which means it will store data for that module in a relational database).

You can refer to ejabberd documentation for MUC module: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modmuc

Once your MySQL is configured and schema is loaded, you can set `db_type` to `odbc` on a case by case basis to choose MySQL for that module.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, just wondering would this have any impact on clustering etc...?

Comment: No impact on clustering no. The module backend are independent from the clustering "engine".